# Creating an event link on a wall (publish event)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I'm currently trying to create an application, which allows me to post links to group walls.
At the moment it is already working and does create working links like a charm :) 
 
My problem now is the following: I want to share fb events. If you only share a normal link (for example http://www.deviantart.com), fb perfectly gets the metadata out of the link an creates a correct preview.
But if i add a facebook event, it doesn't work correctly. It just creates a link (with matching title) without a preview or additional information. I want it to create the "normal" shared event preview. with date, location, preview, attending and the possibility to attend to the event by just clicking on the preview button.

My goal is to get the same behaviour as when you manually copy and paste a facebook event url
I'm using the graph api
I just can't figure out a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Where do u want to share the events ?
2. have u look at this FAQ [developers facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/) ?

Here is a PHP solution, dont know if U are working in PHP, but its a great ex. [PHP EX.](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Facebook-Programming-API-Events-P852.html)

Comment: I want to share the event to a groups wall.
Yes i have looked at FQL but that doesn't help me. Getting the information about the event is absolutely no problem. The problem is the creation of the link itself, for you can only give fb a link or a link with description, caption, picture, ... but in both cases, it doesn't create the same preview as if i just would add an event html to a normal post. i'm using c# with a webclient. the php solution doesn't fit my needs, for it creates an own output and not the "genuine" fb event link. try https://www.facebook.com/events/541785459232897/